# Double CallBack in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am not sure why the following piece of code fires call back twice:

```
request(url, function(error, response, html) {
                    if(!error){
                        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

                        $('.globleRank').filter(function(){
                            var data = $(this);
                            rank_global = .children().first().text().trim();
                            json.rank_global = rank_global;            
                        })

                        url = 'http://www.trafficestimate.com/www.'+site;
                        request(url, function(error, response, html) {
                            if(!error){
                                var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                                $('.chart-yoy span').filter(function(){ 

                                    var visits = $(this).children().first().text();

                                    json.visits = visits;        

                                    dat[site].push(json);                                       
                                    fs.writeFile(country_inp, JSON.stringify(dat, null, 4), function(err){
                                        console.log('Data successfully written for '+site+'! - Check your project directory for the '+country_inp+' file');
                                    })     
                                })

                            }
                        });



                    }      
                });
```

The console output is:

Data successfully written for Go.com! - Check your project directory for the US file
Data successfully written for Go.com! - Check your project directory for the US file

So the write is happening twice.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there are multiple `$('.chart-yoy span')` elements, which will make the `.filter()` callback execute multiple times.

Maybe you want to do

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html);
$('.chart-yoy span').each(function () {
    var visits = $(this).children().first().text();
    json.visits = visits;
    dat[site].push(json);
});
fs.writeFile(country_inp, JSON.stringify(dat, null, 4), function (err) {
    console.log('Data successfully written for ' + site + '! - Check your project directory for the ' + country_inp + ' file');
});
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks. It was due to multiple elements. I needed the first one so modified your code a bit